# Google Drive Python API Resumable media (chunked upload) slow

Tags: python, windows, google-api, google-api-python-client

I'm getting a max of around 20Mbps on any file upload which is resumable=True and chunked (regardless of chunksize), however I get my full internet speed of 180Mbps upload on the same file when not using this method. The problem is that if the file is too big to fit in memory (or even threading many uploads) the computer will run out of memory and I will have to use chunked upload which is just too slow.

Shared code between both examples:

```
import os
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build, MediaFileUpload

def create_drive_service(user_email,SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_FILE,SCOPES=None):
    if SCOPES is None: SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_FILE)
    credentials = credentials.with_scopes(SCOPES)
    credentials = credentials.with_subject(user_email)
    return build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
#
# Fill in the following
#
jsonpath = 'c:\\path\\to\\service_account.json'
service = create_drive_service('user@domain',jsonpath)
filename = 'filename.ext'
filepath = 'c:\\path\\to\\folder\\' + filename
parent_id = ''
```

Code that is slow:

```
file_metadata = {"name":filename,"parents":[parent_id]}
media = MediaFileUpload(filepath,chunksize=-1,resumable=True)
request = service.files().create(body=file_metadata,media_body=media,fields='id')
while response is None:
    status, response = request.next_chunk()
file = request.execute()
```

Code that works full-speed but not if the file is too big to fit in memory:

```
file_metadata = {"name":filename,"parents":[parent_id]}
media = MediaFileUpload(filepath,resumable=False)
request = service.files().create(body=file_metadata,media_body=media,fields='id').execute()
```

How can I upload a large file without having to worry about running out of memory and not be limited to 20Mbps?

Comment: This seems like an issue that should probably be raised on the repo in question. Which, you've already done and didn't mention in your post: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/625

Comment: I posted here first per the repo guidelines. I've also asked on other sites as well and if someone provides helpful information I will update the rest.